# AS assembler ARM Raspberry PI 3 linking with C libraries?

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, arm, raspberry-pi3

I am learning how to program on my raspberry pi. When i compile I use the `as` and `ld` commands to compile and link. I want to link with libc and use malloc but not use `gcc` as my compiler. I tried linking with /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so

Here is what I typed (edit):

```
as test.s -o test.o
ld -o test test.o /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so
./test
```

it compiled and linked, but when I try to run it, it says test is not found

Here is `test.s`:

```
.global _start
.extern malloc

_start:
    mov R0, #4
    bl malloc
    mov R0, #0
    mov R7, #1
    svc 0
.end
```

Is this ok?
Or do I need to do something more?
Any help would be appreciated?

EDIT here is what I am doing (don't forget to initialize C if using some of its functions!):

```
ld -o test /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so test.o -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

Comment: How did you try to run it if it says test is not found? That would mean it can’t find the executable. `./test`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen exactly, it can't seem to locate it, but the binary is produced

Comment: So could you include how exactly you’re trying to run the executable?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ok updated

Comment: Do not pass libraries by passing the name of the shared object.  Instead, simply pass `-lc` after all object files to link in the libc.  If it is not found, also pass `-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` to tell the linker where to find it.

Comment: @fuz so do you mean like `ld -o test test.o -lc -L/usr/lib/arm-Linux-gnueabihf`?

Comment: @yosmo78 No, options like `-L` go before operands.  `-l` counts as an operand, not an option.  So it's `ld -L/usr/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf -o test test.o -lc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the path to the dynamic linker to ld by `-dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` else it uses `/usr/lib/ld.so.1` which does not exist.

Note: While this produces an exectuable which can be run, I doubt it works properly as libc is used but not initalized.

Comment: also would the command be `ld -o test /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so test.o -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`

Comment: may I ask, what is the best way to initialize it, if you know how? also is the command above ok^? it works for me but does it do what you are thinking?
@FPK @ FPK

Comment: 1) glibc initialization is tricky, if you really want to know its details, study the startup files of glibc. Instead I would recommend to write the main function in assembler instead of C and let the startup files do their job. 2) Though malloc might might work in the example above but I wouldn't bet on that it works in all cases properly.